# Limit Row Display on Left Join with Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query which first is selecting one row from table cases and after that I have selection of 5 rows from join table payments. The results of the select is showing 5 results. I would like to limit it to show only one result the first select but still ti have selected all the 5 results from the join table in the memory.

My query so far is the following:

```
SELECT c.*,  
DATE_FORMAT( ADDDATE(c.proposal_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AS expiration_date_30,  
(SELECT name FROM members rp WHERE rp.id = c.resonsible_partner) as responsible_partner,            
FROM cases c 
LEFT JOIN payments AS inv ON inv.caseid = c.id 
WHERE c.id = $id
```

Any Help will be welcome!

Sample output in this case should display:

from table cases should display `c.*` on screen: `id, casename, proposal_date` this is what is should controls how many rows will have to be displayed.

```
id  | casename | proposal_date |
------------------------------
300 | One      | 2016-05-05    |
```

from table payments should display: `payment_percentage_01 = 25, payment_percentage_02 = 30, payment_number_01 = 1, payment_number_02 = 2`

```
id | caseid | payment_percentage | payment number |
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 300    |        25          |        1       |
2  | 300    |        30          |        2       |
```

Comment: Could you show sample input and output?  Have the result stored in memory sounds like you want a view, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You're against running two queries back to back for display purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a table pivot issue, not sure about if your really want this, but just try it, maybe work:

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    DATE_FORMAT( ADDDATE(c.proposal_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AS expiration_date_30,
    -- (SELECT name FROM members rp WHERE rp.id = c.resonsible_partner) as responsible_partner,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN p.payment_percentage END) AS payment_percentage_01,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.id = 2 THEN p.payment_percentage END) AS payment_percentage_02,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN p.`payment number` END) AS payment_number_01,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.id = 2 THEN p.`payment number` END) AS payment_number_02
FROM cases c
LEFT JOIN payments p
ON c.id = p.caseid
GROUP BY c.id
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

***Edited:***

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN p.id = ''',
      id,
      ''' THEN p.payment_percentage END) AS payment_percentage',
      id
    ), ',',
     CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN p.id = ''',
      id,
      ''' THEN p.`payment number` END) AS payment_number',
      id
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM payments;
SET @sql = CONCAT('
    SELECT c.*,
    DATE_FORMAT( ADDDATE(c.proposal_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY),''%Y-%m-%d'') AS expiration_date_30, '
   , @sql
   , ' FROM cases c
       LEFT JOIN payments p
       ON c.id = p.caseid
       GROUP BY c.id;');

-- SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: the only problem is that p.id is unknown value, the compassion should be WHERE c.id = p.caseid

Comment: @JohnSiniger So if p.id has 3,you will want another columns `payment_percentage_03`, `payment_number_03`, won't you?

Comment: I think what I have to do is change the select, first select the table payments and then select the table cases since from payments I have multiple rows selections and from cases only one.

Comment: @JohnSiniger When you want to pivot table, and column is dynamic, you have to create a dynamic query to do that, check my edited answer please.